Resolving SHA-1 Error and 'unable to load script' in Lerna React Native Project
I have started a lerna project using npx lerna init
package.json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start:gamecenter": "cd packages/GameCenter && react-native run-android --port=8083"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**"
    ]  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^8.1.9"
  }
}

lerna.json
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "npmClient": "yarn"

}

in packages section I have created 2 react native project named Bingo , GameCenter
without changing metro config I get the following error;
 ERROR  ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\console.js is not computed.
         Potential causes:
           1) You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
           2) Check `blockList` in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:181:13)
    at Transformer._getSha1 (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:15:26)
    at Transformer.transformFile (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:92:19)
    at Bundler.transformFile (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:43:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.transform (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:134:12)
    at async transform (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:164:26)
    at async visit (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:82:29)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async buildSubgraph (C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\newtest\packages\Bingo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:103:3)

when I updated the metro.config.js as following
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: __dirname,
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules')],
  resolver: {
    blockList: [/.*\/node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/],
  },
};

I get the following error
unable to load script make sure you re either running metro ( run npx react-native start) or that your bundle index.android.bundle is packaged correctly for release

I did not modify any react native files How may I solve the issue
React native 0.76.5
node v20.18.0
"lerna": "^8.1.9"

